# How to access all files from Windows phone SD card?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sd-card

I am trying to access all files and folders from SD card of windows phone. I am able to get only few file types like .pdf,.log, .mdx.
I am also registering FileTypes in WMAppManifest.xml. I am not able to get .jpg , .png , .mp3 files. The following is the code for supported file types.

```
  <SupportedFileTypes>
      <FileType ContentType="application/gpx">.gpx</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="image/jpeg">.jpg</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="image/png">.png</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="image/jpeg">.JPG</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="application/pdf">.pdf</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="audio/mpeg">.mp3</FileType>
    </SupportedFileTypes>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not Possible to get Reserved File types from Windows Phone 8 SD card. Also there is no Write access as of now.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything all right. Simply you can't do that becoause these files are [reserved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
You can tell user to change extension (while copying from Computer or other source) then copy it to internal storage (changing extension to the right one).
I also hope this will change in the future.

Comment: Thankyou.I found out the same thing. There is no point in SDcard access as most types are reserved. Hoping for the change.

Comment: Hi, I have found an app(on store) which can read png files from the SD card. How is it possible?

Comment: Maybe it's not a third party App, have you tried it? What's the link to App? I would also like to know if there are some changes in politics.

Comment: I tried it. Here is the link http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/file-manager-free/5f2122de-a3e6-47d7-8037-21585e0e0c4c

Comment: @Kumar I think the best will be if you write an e-mail to author of the App. He maight be happy with your feedback and maybe will share his knowledge.